# Refactoring if statements when reading keywords from a string

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to programming but have been a long time lurker on SO.

I'm currently studying at university and I'm having a little trouble with writing a program that is essentially a very basic calculator where the input and output are displayed to the user as Hexadecimal.

Most of the code is good to go, but I was wondering if there was a way to refactor this particular code so it doesn't (essentially) just use a large block of if statements to link together the operator the user enters to the it's corresponding function?

This is a snippet of what I've done, and what I need to refactor.

Personally I feel like I should either be nesting or perhaps taking advantage of loops for this, but I don't have enough knowledge to know for sure!

Thanks heaps.

```cs
    int main() {
    printf ("Type in an expression: ");
    scanf ("%x %s %x", &a, op, &b);
    if (strcmp (op, "add") == 0)
    {
        add(a, b);
    }   
    if (strcmp (op, "sub") == 0)
    {
        sub(a, b);
    }
    if (strcmp (op, "and") == 0)
    {
        band (a, b);
    }
    if (strcmp (op, "or") == 0) 
    {
        bor (a, b);
    }
    /* ...... and so on .....*/ 

}
```

Comment: You could have an array of structs, containing a string and a function pointer and loop over that looking to match the string then call the function. Another way would be to create a hash table, that might be a bit heavy given you have a fairly low number of operations.

Comment: Also, be careful about that `scanf` call. You're not checking its return value and `"%s"` in scanf is dangerous -- your user could overflow your buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `else if`s. (If `op` matches `"add"` it's most definitely pointless to test if it also matches `"or"` (etc.).)

The "pro" way to do this kind of parsing is with a lexer (such as [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)) and a parser generator (such as [bison](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/bison/)), which allow you to generate C code that matches all possibilities simultaneously, but those take a little bit of time to learn. For simple stuff, you're good with `if else` and `strcmp`.

Comment: Good answer, I'm definitely going to look in to learning the lexer method you mentioned- it seems interesting :) In the mean time I'll just use else if like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @MackenzyBrown It's powerful (you can rather easily create a full  blown C parser with it) but takes some time to learn.  Don't feel bad about the `strcmp` with `if else`, though. Lots of "real" C projects handle CLI option parsing with that kind of code.